# Redirect /mobile/REQUEST_URI to /REQUEST_URI

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

This is what I currently have

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/mobile/ https://www.websitename.com/?
RedirectMatch 301 ^/m/ https://www.websitename.com/?
```

Im trying to redirect if user types /m/testpage.php to /testpage.php

the above example always redirects to same url.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
RewriteRule ^mobile/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^m/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```